# Issue with XPage access to documents from another database

Tags: data-binding, xpages, acl, lotus-domino

I have 2 databases in one server, a Web App db containing XPages only, and another database containing documents. When I tried to open a document in Xpage, an error appears saying that I don't have access to the document (I did a checking using db.queryAccess(myUserName) and found out that I don't have access to the document database, even though my user name is specified directly as Manager). I created a new copy of the document database, then points my web app db to that. Here I have access to the documents! I had implemented this before and this is the first time I had this problem. What are the probable problem(s) with my original document database? I already did a fixup and compacting, but to no avail. Please help me... Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the "Maximum Internet name and password" option?

Comment: Thanks a lot @SvenHasselbach!!! I've been solving this for 2 days! You should put it as answer :D

Comment: I have had this same issue several times. @Sven: post as the answer so it can be accepted and recognized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check the the "Maximum Internet name and password" option in the ACL settings. This option overrides every ACL entry: If you are Manager but the option is set to "No Access" - you have no access.